# How to use _mat-tabs-background() sass mixin in Angular Material 2

Tags: sass, angular-material2

How to use _mat-tabs-background() mixin availabel in angular material 2?
Here is my custom theme for MdTab

```
/* Import your custom input theme file so you can call the custom-input-theme function */
@import './components/header/header-links/app-header-links-component-theme.scss';

// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

@include _mat-tabs-background(#ff0000);
```

Here is the error message...

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"preci
sion":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/app/app.theme.scss
Module build failed: 
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Backtrace:
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1107, in function `map-get`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1107, in function `mat-color`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:3293, in mixin `-mat-tabs-background`
        stdin:16
      in D:\My_Projects\HZone_Web\Final Project\hardware-zone 1.1\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1107, column 11)
Error: 
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map
```

Answer (score 0):

You're **NOT** supposed to use private theming from the source code. Instead, use this:

`styles.scss` (Or whatever your filename is):

```scss
@include mat-tabs-theme($theme); // The theme
```

Then, you can use the `backgroundColor` input on `md-tab` (only available if you installed `2.0.0-beta.10` and above):

```html
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="One" backgroundColor="primary"> <!-- Can be accent/ warn -->
        Content here
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Two" backgroundColor="accent"> <!-- Can be accent/ warn -->
        Content here
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```